# Error creating protected columns with google sheet create api

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am following the  google sheet v4 api doumentation to create google sheet with protected columns (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create)

I am able to create sheet without using **protectedRange** in api, using it always gives error, below are request /response i am getting

```
  "properties": {
    "title": "NEW SHEET"
  },
  "sheets": [
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "rowData": [
            {
              "values": [
                {
                  "userEnteredValue": {
                    "numberValue": 10
                  }
                },
                {
                  "userEnteredValue": {
                    "numberValue": 20
                  }
                },
                {
                  "userEnteredValue": {
                    "numberValue": 30
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "protectedRanges": [
        {
          "description": "Locked columns",
          "range": {
            "sheetId": 0,
            "startColumnIndex": 0,
            "endColumnIndex": 2
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

response

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid sheets[1].protectedRanges[0]: No grid with id: 0",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to create new Spreadsheet.
- When the new Spreadsheet is created, you want to add the protected ranges.
- In your sample, you want to create new Spreadsheet including a sheet which has the protected columns "A" and "B" and values of `10, 20, 30` in the cells "A1:C1".

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Issue and solution:

- In your request body, please include the property of `protectedRanges` to the 1st index of `sheets`.
- Please set the sheet ID at `properties`.

#### Modified request body:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "title": "NEW SHEET"
  },
  "sheets": [
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "rowData": [
            {
              "values": [
                {
                  "userEnteredValue": {
                    "numberValue": 10
                  }
                },
                {
                  "userEnteredValue": {
                    "numberValue": 20
                  }
                },
                {
                  "userEnteredValue": {
                    "numberValue": 30
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "protectedRanges": [
        {
          "description": "Locked columns",
          "range": {
            "startColumnIndex": 0,
            "endColumnIndex": 2,
            "sheetId": 0
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "sheetId": 0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

- For example, when `"sheetId": 123` is set, the sheet is created as the sheet ID of `123`.
- You can also test above request body at [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create?apix_params=%7B%22resource%22%3A%7B%22properties%22%3A%7B%22title%22%3A%22NEW%20SHEET%22%7D%2C%22sheets%22%3A%5B%7B%22data%22%3A%5B%7B%22rowData%22%3A%5B%7B%22values%22%3A%5B%7B%22userEnteredValue%22%3A%7B%22numberValue%22%3A10%7D%7D%2C%7B%22userEnteredValue%22%3A%7B%22numberValue%22%3A20%7D%7D%2C%7B%22userEnteredValue%22%3A%7B%22numberValue%22%3A30%7D%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D%5D%2C%22protectedRanges%22%3A%5B%7B%22description%22%3A%22Locked%20columns%22%2C%22range%22%3A%7B%22startColumnIndex%22%3A0%2C%22endColumnIndex%22%3A2%2C%22sheetId%22%3A0%7D%7D%5D%2C%22properties%22%3A%7B%22sheetId%22%3A0%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D).

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.create](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Bipin Chandra Tripathi Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.